# Keep multi-character delimiter

Tags: php

I have a string

```
$string = "hi!n!my!n!name!n!is!n!bob";
```

I want to split it by the '!n!'
I've tried something like:

```
$splitstring = preg_split("!n!", $string,-1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

but it removes all instances of 'n' instead of !n!
so if i `print_r` the array, it'll look something like:

```
Array(
[0]=>hi!
[1]=>!my!
[2]=>!
[3]=>!ame!
[4]=>!is!
[5]=>!bob
)
```

it would split every occurrence of 'n'. not !n! (a 3 character delimiter) like I wanted.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: You realise that `!` is not being included in your regexp, just the `n`.... because `!` is being treated as the delimiter in the regexp..... `$splitstring = preg_split("/!n!/", $hi,-1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);`

Comment: Ah You realize that the `!` are left? What do you do? -> **Use google!** What function do you use `preg_split()` so -> 1. https://google.com 2. `PHP preg_split()`

Comment: I guess `$hi` is supposed to be the same as `$string`?

Comment: why would you ever have a string like that?

Comment: thedanny because I want to store multiple sets of data in a single row on  a txt file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, first of all thanks for all your replies. using / worked but it removed all of the delimiters (!n!). I suspected that PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE wasn't working. So, I found [this](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=16512&edit=1). The fix was something like:

$splitstring = preg_split("/(!n!)/", $string,-1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

putting the brackets around the delimiter outputted:

```
[0]hi
[1]!n!
[2]my
[3]!n!
[4]name
[5]!n!
[6]is
[7]!n!
[8]bob
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You could just use explode: http://php.net/explode

```
$parts = explode('!n!', $string);
```

To reproduce the string you started with you can do this:

```
$string = implode('!n!', $parts);
```

Finally, if you're looking to keep the delimeter(s) you can always add them back in. It's not clear whether you want them on the start or end of each entity (as your starting string uses them purely as a separator). You could do that like so:

```
foreach ($parts as &$part)
{
    $part = '!n!'.$part.'!n!';
}
```

Comment: Explode wouldn't work because I want to keep the delimiters

Comment: In your own words... `but it removes all instances of 'n' instead of !n!`

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my answer which might help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need delimiters (e.g. `/`) in your regular expression:

```
$splitstring = preg_split("/!n!/", $string,-1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```